# Get Seperate Total of Two MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have two table called questions and entries. I  want get separate total of both table using one query. Like  questions 10 and entries 20. I have tried like below but its giving me two row as totalEntries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalEntries FROM quiz_entries UNION SELECT COUNT(*) as totalQuestions FROM quiz_questions
```

Let me know if any one can help me for get seperate result for both table like totalEntries 20 and totalQuestions  10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use each query as an expression that returns the number of rows in each table in a `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quiz_entries) as totalEntries, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quiz_questions) as totalQuestions
```

Comment: WOW ! Thanks a lot sir! it have solved my puzzle. I will accept answer in some minutes when its allow me to do it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this also. Because temp table solves our complex problem too.

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblEntries')) IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tblEntries

IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblQuestions')) IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tblQuestions

DECLARE @quizEntriesCount INT
DECLARE @quizQuestionsCount  INT

SET @quizEntriesCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM quiz_entries)
SET @quizQuestionsCount  =(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM quiz_questions)

SELECT @quizEntriesCount AS quizEntriesCount, @quizQuestionsCount  AS quizQuestionCount,
```